# ExFAT does not support resizing - how can I partition it in order to use TimeMachine backup?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, partition, exfat

I have a **4TB external drive** formatted as **ExFAT** file system with **single partition**, and I've already stored approximately about **800GB** of files on it, and I decided to create a partition on this drive to use TimeMachine backup. But then I tried to add a partition (Mac OS Extended Journaled) to it and I found out that ExFAT does not support resizing, so I realized that the only thing I can do about it is to move away all the files on this drive temporarily and reformat this drive with two partitions. (I can't buy a new hard drive and I don't have another hard drive that's empty)

Is there ANY other way (it seems that's it) other than this solution to partition my drive (cause it's gonna take a lot of effort on transferring the files)? Like using windows computer or other third-party application?

Comment: It is more likely that the disk uses MBR which Disk Utility will not resize. Your options are to adjust partition table under Linux (or maybe Windows) or convert to GPT.

Comment: @Milliways Well, my disk is using GUID Partition Table. And how am I suppose to adjust the partition table?